# Automapper mapping Flags Enum from ViewModel to Domain model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, enums, automapper

While trying to translate between my ViewModel and my domain model using AutoMapper I noticed that it does not play well with Enums marked the the Flags attribute.

Here is a quick mockup of the classes:

ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    // array of individual Enum values
    public TestEnum[] TestEnum { get; set; } 
}
```

Domain Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    // single Enum marked with flags attribute
    public TestEnum TestEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum TestEnum
{
    Test1,
    Test2,
    Test3,
    Test4
}
```

This is what I am trying to do. I guess I need a Custom resolver of some sort in my Automapper config because it throws an exception when I do Mapper.Map().

My question: How would I accomplish this?

Bonus question: Is this best practice for handling Flags Enums / Bitmasks in Viewmodel -> Domain models (in a MVVM respect)? If not, what practice would you suggest (using AutoMapper or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd skip AutoMapper and go the model binding route. If you're using ASP.NET MVC, you can hook directly into model binding so that all values are combined into one.

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy. I was hoping to avoid mapping the tons of properties in this enorous VM. A custom model binder would accomplish just that with minimal code. Seems it would be best to avoid Flagged Enums in domain models entirely and just do it the old way.

Comment: Any example of the resulting code? That would help me also!

Answer (score 5):

When mapping to the view model, you can try to use `Enum.GetValues()` and LINQ to get a list of enum values. To map back to the model, try using `Aggregate()`...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TestModel, TestViewModel>()
    .ForMember(v => v.TestEnum, 
        x => x.MapFrom(m => Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestEnum))
                            .Cast<TestEnum>()
                            .Where(e => (e & m) > 0)
                            .ToList()))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(m => m.TestEnum,
        x => x.MapFrom(v => v.Aggregate((i, j) => i | j));
```

As for whether this is the best approach, it really depends on how the view model is being used. Currently, the view model doesn't contain flags that aren't set; do you need them for rendering the view?